# Como reiniciar mi app android cuando el usuario Fuerza su detención

Tags: java, android

estoy haciendo una app android en la que hay un servicio acoplado a la app por detrás que funciona aún que la app esté cerrada. Cuando el usuario la cierra de la manera habitual el servicio se reinicia pero cuando le da a Forzar Detención en ajustes no, me gustaría saber si hay alguna manera de cambiar esto, es decir, que cuando forzamos la detención el servicio se reinicie.

Gracias!

Comment: Hola @LauraInsuaRegueiro. Cuando fuerzas la detención de una app la detienes completamente, obligas al sistema operativo a acabar completamente con la ejecución de la App y el servicio que pueda haber creado. Esto pasa con todas Apps.

Comment: Hola @PabloSimonDiEstefano, con el Servicio de Google Play no, en cuanto le das a Forzar Detención se reinicia al instante. Y eso era lo que quería!

Comment: Revisa lo que has dicho bien porque creo que no es así (acabo de hacer la prueba). Lo que tienes que asegurarte es que fuerzas la detención de TODOS los servicios y verás como no se reinician. Lo harán cuando reinicies la App o el smartphone (si el servicio está configurado para iniciarse al reiniciar el smartphone)

Comment: Acabo de forzar la detención del Servicio "Service Google Play" y se ha reiniciado al momento. Eso es a lo que me refería.